# how to store in one cell rows value what have the same name but different id?

Tags: mysql, sql, string-aggregation

```
insert into demo values ('1','name1','Text1');
insert into demo values ('2','name1','Text2');
insert into demo values ('3','name1','Text3');
```

how can I get a row like this ?

```
id | name  | value
1  | name1 | Text1 + Text2 + Text3
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: MYSQL server phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**MYSQL:**

Use `GROUP_CONCAT` function.

```
SELECT MIN(id), name, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Value SEPARATOR ' + ') AS Value
FROM demo
GROUP BY name
```

**DEMO**

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d75aca/2

**MSSQL:**

```
SELECT MIN(id), name,
       Value = STUFF((
          SELECT '+ ' + di.value + ' '
          FROM demo di
          WHERE d.name = di.name
          GROUP BY di.value
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM demo d
GROUP BY name
```

**DEMO:**

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d75ac/2

Comment: SELECT MIN(id), name, GROUP_CONCAT(distinct Value SEPARATOR ' + ') AS Value
FROM demo
GROUP BY name

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle:**

```
SELECT MIN(ID), NAME, LISTAGG(VALUE,'+') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY NAME) AS VALUE
FROM DEMO 
GROUP BY NAME
```